# Switched distros; Broke grub

Tags: boot, grub, boot-loader

My HDD uses GPT. I've set my boot mode to UEFI only. My partitions are:

```
/dev/sda

/dev/sda1 Grub 300MiB FAT32
/dev/sda2 Linux 97.66GiB ext4
/dev/sda3 Windows 97.66GiB NTFS
/dev/sda4 Microsoft_Reserved 16MiB unknown
/dev/sda5 Data 726.13GiB NTFS 
/dev/sda6 Swap 9.76GiB linux-swap
```

I had set up grub on `/boot/efi` on `/dev/sda1` during the installation of Sparky linux on `/dev/sda2`. Everything was working fine and I could choose between Linux, its recovery, Windows 10 and BIOS from the grub menu when I set it as the first in the boot priority order.

I now replaced Sparky Linux with Solus Linux. But the problem is that grub no longer works. Booting from the grub partition gives me the following error:

```
error: file `/boot/grub/x64_86-efi/normal.mod` not found.
Entering rescue mode
grub rescue>
```

Booting into linux and doing `sudo update-grub` gave me:

```
$ sudo update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found background: /usr/share/backgrounds/splash.tga
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
done
```

but that didn't seem to fix it. My HDD currently has 3 bootloaders I think: Linux, Windows and grub, at least that's the things being shown in the boot priority menu in the BIOS.

**Edit**: I tried to reinstall grub and now I have *two* grub bootloaders, neither of them which work.

Output of `lsblk`:

```
$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   300M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0  97.7G  0 part /
├─sda3   8:3    0  97.7G  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0    16M  0 part 
├─sda6   8:6    0 726.1G  0 part 
└─sda7   8:7    0   9.8G  0 part [SWAP]
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

I'm at a loss as to what to do to fix it. I just want to have the option to select my OS at boot.

Comment: You should backup your data using liveboot usb and then reinstall Windows and Solus

Comment: When you are in grub rescue, what is the output from ls? And did you install Linux to LVs?

Comment: @bu5hman Output of ls: `(hd0) (hd0, gpt7) (hd0, gpt6), (hd0, gpt5) (hd0, gpt4) (hd0, gpt3) (hd0, gpt2) (hd0, gpt1) (cd0)`. Not sure what you mean by 'install Linux to LVs'. I use GPT, so there's no logical volumes or anything (correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: I asked about the LV's because it makes a difference to how to handle the paths to / and /boot/grub and also you need to load another module into grub to handle them at boot. If you are not using LV then hamna shida (no worries).

Comment: GPT and LVM are different things. You can have one without the other. Put the output of `ls` in your question, please. Always include all relevant information in the question.

Comment: "I tried to reinstall grub and now I have two grub bootloaders, neither of them which work." How do you know you have two?

Comment: @bu5hman's instructions mostly look correct. Have you tried following them?

Answer (score 1):

[This linux.com link](https://www.linux.com/learn/how-rescue-non-booting-grub-2-linux) will explain how to recover from a broken grub through grub-rescue.

Basically you need to

```
ls (hd0,1)/
ls (hd0,2)/
```

and so on until you find the /boot/grub directory and also the vmlinuz and initrd.img files. Although the link expects these files to be in /boot/vmlinuz-x.y.z.blah you will probably see them as links in / which just point to the current kernel and initrd. If you don't, then just look in /boot/ and amend the below accordingly.

Judging from your lsblk /boot/grub may be on (hd0,1) and the rest of your linux OS is on (hd0,2).

Once you have found the partition with your OS, you could verify this with

```
cat (hd0,2)/etc/fstab
```

If these assumptions are correct then

```
set prefix=(hd0,1)/boot/grub  #tells grub where it can find insmod etc
set root=(hd0,2)              #tells grub where to find / 
insmod normal                 #loads normal module
normal                        #executes normal
insmod linux                  #loads the linux module
linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda2 #executes linux, loads the kernel and tells it where to find /
initrd /initrd.img            #loads the initrd
boot
```

Note the root=/dev/sdx command. If you omit this or point it to the wrong partition then you will get a kernel panic. If so then just [REISUB](http://blog.kember.net/articles/reisub-the-gentle-linux-restart/) and start again.

If the above doesn't work then try again changing the first line to

```
set prefix=(hd0,2)/boot/grub
```

Once you are in you can reinstall grub.

I like to use grub-customizer when fixing grub simply because it lets me see the boot options and setup in grub while I am still in linux and fix any issues before going for the reboot.

Comment: This mostly looks on target, though I'm not currently in a position to test this. But I seem to remember, from my own experience with similar breakages, that once `normal` has been executed, then I get access to the GRUB menu and don't need to type things in manually. Maybe `normal` brings the GRUB menu up? I forget. Can anyone confirm/clarify?

Comment: As often as not, as soon as normal is executed then you get grub back and can boot from the menu. But it doesn't hurt to be aware of the whole process.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. Assuming, of course, there is a usable grub config/menu file in the first place.

Comment: If not, then Cool Guy probably needs to reinstall grub as per Time4Tea direction below, but if reinstallation hasn't worked before then there may be another issue. Hence my previous query re LV's, since an installation to LV will require additional grub modules to handle them at boot as well as being to identify the actual location of grub ((hd0,1)/boot/grub or wherever).

Comment: LV should be handled automatically in theory. I use LV and don't have to do anything, in theory. Most likely the menu is still there and usable, since it exists on the system proper. But there is probably no point in discussing this further, since the poster has not responded to anything you or I have written.

Comment: Anyway, good work on the answer. I've upvoted. And welcome to U&L - it looks like you just started being active here.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to re-install GRUB by doing the following:

1. Boot up into Linux using a live USB/CD
2. chroot to your Linux
   root partition (I assume /dev/sda2)
3. mount /dev/sda1 at /boot/efi
4. run sudo grub-install

What happens if you try that?

(NOTE: I recommend that you make sure your critical data is backed up first)

Comment: So, I did `sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt` and then `sudo chroot /mnt` which worked as expected. However, `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /boot/efi` failed with `mount: /boot/efi: mount point does not exist`. So I did `cd /boot` and then `mkdir efi`. Trying to mount the first partition again gave me `mount: /boot/efi: special device /dev/sda1 does not exist.`

Comment: Can you post the output of the `lsblk` command? You may need to invoke mount with the `-t msdos` option, to indicate that /dev/sda1 is using a fat32 (Windows) filesystem.

Comment: Added the output of `lsblk` in the question. Using `sudo grub-install` gave me `grub-install: error: /usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi/modinfo.sh doesn't exist. Please specify --target or --directory.` when I used it directly from the installed linux and not via the Live USB

Comment: Using `mount -t msdos /dev/sda1 /boot/efi` via the live USB gave me the same error as before `mount: /boot/efi: special device /dev/sda1 does not exist.`

Comment: Ok. So, The problem was after chrooting, I couldn't mount any of the partitions. So I first mounted /dev/sda1 at /boot/efi, chrooted to /mnt which I had mounted to /dev/sda2. `sudo update-grub` gives me `/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: cannot find a device for / (is /dev mounted?)` while `sudo grub-install` gives `Installing for the i386-pc platform. grub-install: error: install device isn't specified.`. Both `sudo grub-install /boot/efi` and `sudo grub-install /dev/sda1` gives me `Installing for the i386-pc platform. grub-install: error: cannot find a device for /boot/efi (is /dev mounted?)`

Comment: If you are mounting /dev/sda2 at /mnt before chrooting, then /dev/sda1 should be mounted at /mnt/boot/efi, so that after chrooting, its path will be /boot/efi. Perhaps try doing that and then `sudo grub-install`?

Comment: I did `sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt`, `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/efi`, `sudo chroot /mnt`. All the commands tried [before](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/402326/switched-distros-broke-grub?noredirect=1#comment722068_403395) gave the same errors as in that comment

Comment: sudo parted -l       please

Comment: From what you say, it sounds to me like there is some problem with the EFI System Partition. After you mount it, are you able to browse it normally? At this point, I would probably look into how you can recover a damaged EFI System Partition. Repair it for Windows first and get Windows booting, then you should be able to run grub-install, as if you were installing the dual-boot from scratch. Again, just make sure you back up your Linux data, in case Windows wipes it!

Comment: Sites such as this one might help: [https://www.partition-tool.com/resource/partition-recovery/restore-repair-deleted-efi-boot-partition-in-windows-10-8-7.html](https://www.partition-tool.com/resource/partition-recovery/restore-repair-deleted-efi-boot-partition-in-windows-10-8-7.html)

Comment: @Cool Guy did you make any progress with this? After you chroot, is /boot/efi still mounted? Are you able to browse any files there?