# How to fix faulty drive labelling?

Tags: kali-linux, initramfs

I was installing Kali Linux 2016.2 64-bit on my laptop. In my laptop, hard disk is always denoted by sda while flash drives by sdb or sdc.

But during the installation, while selecting partition on which the system was to be installed, I noticed that the flash drive was shown as sda while hard disk by sdb, I installed Kali Linux on /dev/sdb2 (the second partition of hard drive, which is normally denoted as /dev/sda2).

On booting the system after the install, grub menu showed up normally but Kali did not boot normally, it showed me error message: something like,

> /dev/sdb2 cannot be found

and showed an (initramfs) console.

I found that my computer switches the name of hard disk from sda to sdb in the presence of a flash drive (which becomes sda, while successive flash drives shows up as sdc, etc). So In the absence of flash drive, the system does not boot and shows error and initramfs console.

How to fix labelling of drives?

Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)

Comment: It's not a duplicate.

Comment: But it is a duplicate of [Kali dual boot not working without plugged in usb stick](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/404709/kali-dual-boot-not-working-without-plugged-in-usb-stick/404789#404789)

Comment: I am not dual-booting, I am mono-booting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably need to manually mount your root filesystem to `/mnt` or similar, make sure that `/dev`, `/proc` and `/sys` are available within it (by `mount --bind` commands, perhaps?), then `chroot` to your root filesystem, fix your `/etc/fstab` and regenerate your initramfs file so that it will contain the fixed `/etc/fstab`.

You should also check your bootloader's boot options: if there is a `root=/dev/sdb2` option, you should adjust that to match reality.

Comment: Thank you, Ihave already done some of the above steps, I will try fixing fstab and initramfs as you said.